# Jquery how to make div visible after valid mail is written

Tags: jquery, input

I wanna make form, which will show its next part, after valid email adress is written in input. I have some code to validate, but i need some code, which will wait until email adress is in input.

```
<input style="border-radius: 4px;" name="editsubsemail" type="text" id="editsubsemail" size="40"/><br /><br />
```

This is jquery code and i need to replace that .click (just placeholder) with something, that will check, if that "editsubsemail" is filled with email

```
var visibility_edit = false;
$("#changesubs-wraper").click(function(){
if( visibility_edit == false ){
    $('#change-info-wraper').show("slow");
    $('#delete-subs-wraper').show("slow"); 
    visibility_edit = true;
} else {
    $('#change-info-wraper').hide("slow");
    $('#delete-subs-wraper').hide("slow");   
    visibility_edit = false;
}
});
```

Comment: Without your current code its not possible to tell what additional code you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [this](http://css-tricks.com/examples/SeminarRegTutorial/) seminar registration demo form on css-tricks. It looks like it could solve your problem with a little tweaking. [Here](https://github.com/CSS-Tricks/Step-by-Step-Seminar-Registration) is the source.

Comment: Ou thanks to both of you ;) (Harry and Sumurai8) - that seminar registration is right what i need and that code helped too.
thx

Answer (score 0):

For: `<input name='email' type='email' id='email'>` and `<div id='somediv'></div>`

This is some untested code:

```
$('#email').on( 'change', function() {
  if( email_regex_must_be_here ) {
    //this is a valid email
    $('#somediv').show();
  }
  else {
    $('#somediv').hide();
  }
} );
```

Harry's link might be better at helping you though.